# mongoid array with blanks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using a an array in mongoid to store user roles and it mostly works fine, but I have the problem with rails passing in a blank to an array and mongoid saves it.

```
["", "admin", "editor", "author"]
```

Formtastic does this automatically to avoid another problem, I for get what.  But the problem is that mongoid saves the blank in the array.  How can I tell it to ignore blanks?

```
<input id="user_roles_none" name="user[roles][]" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Code:

```
  field :roles, :type => Array, :default => ["author"]

  ##USER ROLES

  ROLES = %w[admin editor author]

  class << self
    def with_role(*args)
      any_in(:roles => args)
    end
  end
```

I'm sure I could make a callback before_save and remove nils, but surely there's another way I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the roles writer method and do a compact on it.

```
def roles=(values)
  write_attribute(:roles, values.map{|v| v.blank? ? nil : v}.compact)
end
```

[EDIT] :
Like explain on comment by Mik_Die. you can do like :

```
def roles=(values)
  write_attribute(:roles, values.reject(&:blank?)
end
```

Comment: or simple `write_attribute(:roles, values.reject(&:blank?))`